# LINE BOT API internal error (500) on post event but success on get event

Tags: php, api

I did many curl format to send message using LINE BOT API, but always get 500 error.

Here is my last post curl code

```
$apiCall = 'https://trialbot-api.line.me/v1/events';

$params = array();
$params['to'] = ["uf92dfc2702b46be071376c8ff81a4b56"];
$params['toChannel'] = 1383378250;
$params['eventType'] = "138311608800106203";
$params['content'] = [ "contentType" => 1,
                       "toType" => 1,
                       "text" => "the text"];
$string_data = json_encode($params)

$headers = array (
            "Content-Type: application / json; charset = UTF-8",
            "X-Line-ChannelID: 1476460XXX",
            "X-Line-ChannelSecret: 6363d24b1e356c77189137b6362XXXXX",
            "X-Line-Trusted-User-With-ACL: u54bf222a19fd3114e9eb1a3499dXXXXX"
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiCall);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($params));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $string_data);
$jsonData = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$results = json_decode($jsonData,TRUE);
```

And here is the result

```
array:2 [
  "statusCode" => "500"
  "statusMessage" => "internal error."
]
```

And this is my get code (proccess successfully)

```
$url = "https://trialbot-api.line.me/v1/profiles?mids=uc02643a656b777f66162e121fa697f82";
$curl = curl_init ($url) ;
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
     'Content-Type: application/json; charset = UTF-8',
     'X-Line-ChannelID: 1476460XXX',
     'X-Line-ChannelSecret: 6363d24b1e356c77189137b6362XXXXX',
     'X-Line-Trusted-User-With-ACL: u54bf222a19fd3114e9eb1a3499dXXXXX')
);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
$output = curl_exec ($curl) ;
curl_close($curl);
```

The question are :

1. why my code work successfully on GET event but not on POST event?
2. is it true that error 500 is the error from the server (LINE server) ?

any advice and answers will really help me.
thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this curl request send messages:

```
curl -X POST \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8' \
-H 'X-Line-ChannelID: 147XXXX741' \   //your channel ID
-H 'X-Line-ChannelSecret: ff9051XXXXXXb5531e3eb633b24c2e73' \   //Your channel Secret
-H 'X-Line-Trusted-User-With-ACL: uc866bXXXXXX8b4fbc3f4dd43befd66c9' \  //Your channel mid
-d '{
   "to":["u004ddf56dXXXXXb2f9760e02f0a7b623"], //List of users MID
   "toChannel": 1383378250, //Fixed
   "eventType": "138311608800106203", //Fixed
   "content":{
       "contentType":1,
       "toType":1,
       "text":"hallo"
   }
}' https://trialbot-api.line.me/v1/events
```

Comment: I think the problem is the "to" parameter. The one you want to send message must added your line bot as friend.
You can't send message to the stranger.

In the Basic Information part of LINE developers, You can found a QR code, just scanning this and add your bot as friend. Then try to send it works.    http://screencast.com/t/fFkjfiQdV